# cpu is 100% used, yet no application shows significant usage

Tags: macos, imac, performance, cpu

Since a few days my IMac started showing weird behaviour.
In Activity Monitor it shows that my CPU is 100% used. Literally 0% idle, but there are no Applications using anywhere near this much resources.
The highest percentage would be from Activity Monitor itself, but this just uses 2.5% at max.
The amount of CPU used is shared over 'User' and 'System' they both use around 50% CPU at the same time.

Also, the amount of threads running is around 300 to 375, but the sum of all running applications their threads doesn't go over 100.

My question is:
Is there any explanation for this behaviour?
And can I do something against this?

**Info about my Mac:**

**OS :** Mac OS X 10.7.5

**CPU :** 3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

**Memory :** 4 GB 1067 MHz RAM

(iMac Late 2009)

**EDIT:**

After making sure that I was looking at 'All Processes' that are running on my iMac, I found that Norton Deepsight was causing a big part of my issue.
By changing a setting in my Norton-AntiVirus I managed to take atleast 50% of CPU usage away.
Yet my System is still using around 50% to 60% of CPU, which is caused by 'kernel_task' and 'SymDaemon'

Is there a clear reason to why these to processes are using this much CPU?

Comment: Did you select All from the process selection option?

Comment: Okay, I have been pretty stupid there. What I now see is that 'symdeepsight-extractor' is using about 90% CPU.

Comment: Thats probably something you installed. You can check it's details with one of the buttons in the interface and using the open files info you can find where the program is installed and possibly who/what it belongs.

Comment: If you read my 'EDIT' in my main post you will see what caused half of my issue. Now I would like to understand the other half.

Comment: Symdaemon is part of norton by symantec. It's still running causing both the 50% user and 50% system usage. Symdaemon also causes kernel usage.

Comment: Don't use anti virus software. There is no need for that. Problem solved. Please go on.

Comment: @MaxRied well this is kind off harsh, but I do admit that AntiVirus sometimes comes with more trouble than is necessary.

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie Sorry for that, I didn't mean to attack you. But could you elaborate on what kind of software this Antivirus should protect you from?

Comment: @MaxRied Well, what I hope that it does, is protect me from malicious file downloads, which automatically start when opening some websites. Also, having my downloads checked for 'possible' viruses or malicious software seems quite useful to me.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-2435

Comment: @MaxRied very interesting article I must say. Although it is a bit dated (2 years old) it still gives good advice. Especially the General Advice was pretty interesting. Sadly I cannot avoid infection by following these rules, because I simply don't want to stop using uTorrent. Along with that, the article states that I should use an AntiVirus program like 'ClamXav', Im not doing this because I have Norton. The principle is the same. The fact that there are no 'known' viruses for Mac says nothing, in due time Mac could just become as unsafe as Windows or other OS. In my opinion.

Comment: "Last Modified: Jun 13, 2015 10:20 AM" is certainly not two years ago. Besides, how do you think Norton Anti Virus helps you against unknown viruses? It just doesn't. That's not much about opinion.

Comment: @MaxRied That is completely true yes. For the big part it's just 'believing' that it works. Whether the AntiVirus really does a good job (or not), I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some helpful answers I managed to find the answers to this question.

The main cause of this CPU usage is Norton AntiVirus.
A Setting in the AntiVirus called 'Norton Deepsight Community Submission' makes it constantly use around 50% CPU, just to collect data and send this to Norton I guess.

The other 50% is also caused by Norton AntiVirus, yet I am not a 100% sure which setting or process causes this.

Hopefully this helps other people in the future.

Many thanks to the commenters on my main post, which helped me find the cause of this problem.